# Why does the realpath function not work in Cygwin?

Tags: c, cygwin, realpath

```
char *path = "somefile.txt";
char resolved[PATH_MAX] = {0};
realpath(path, resolved);

printf("path is %s, resolved path is %s", path, resolved);
```

In linux env, everything works fine, but if it is built in cygwin env, resolved is "" (empty), why?

Comment: Did you check errno as described here : http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html

Comment: @mbieren it prints "No such file or directory"

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear.   Are you claiming that the file "somefile.txt" actually exists in the current directory?

Comment: @varro The file does not exists. But even file not exists, realpath should return a path to the `${current-folder}/somefile.txt` too. It works under linux env.

Comment: Try passing NULL for 2nd arg and use the return value from realpath(). See e.g. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html and when return value is NULL, use e.g. perror() to print the error status message. Be sure to free() any non-NULL return value. Note that passing a non-null value as the 2nd arg is unsafe as there is no buffer length check, allowing over write of data should your allocation be smaller than the kernel's idea of PATH_MAX. Note as well cygwin uses newlib, rather than glibc so the implementation may be different from linux.

Comment: @NewBee: You say "even file not exists, realpath should return a path to the ${current-folder}/somefile.txt too.".  Why should it?  In fact, the POSIX standard states (https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/realpath.html) "the _realpath()_ function **shall** fail if: ... [ENOENT]
    A component of file_name does not name an existing file or file_name points to an empty string.".  It looks like Cygwin is correct.

Comment: @varro It seems you are right. It's wierd that in `ubuntu16`, `centos62,610,75`, realpath with return an absolute filepath even file not exists (if folder not exist, it will return null too).

Answer (score 0):

The source of `realpath` function is in file `canonicalize.c` . There is such code :

```
if (resolved == NULL)
{
    rpath = malloc (path_max);
    if (rpath == NULL)
    return NULL;
}
else
    rpath = resolved;
```

I think the initialisation you used for array `resolved` library function
perceives as `NULL` and none saving into it.
Try initialise

```
char *resolved;
resolved=malloc(PATH_MAX);

 /* SOME CODE  */

free(resolved);
```

Comment: I donot think malloc(PATH_MAX) has difference with char[PATH_MAX] in this situation.

Comment: Yes, it does failed again.

Comment: Linux uses GNU 'libc.so' . CYGWIN uses own, non compatible with GNU, library 'cygwin1.dll'.